How does the logic of the arithmetic operation properties of equality work to solve equations?
I'm currently reviewing my Pre-Algebra knowledge to further my education. Years ago I took a Calculus and a Proofs course, so I have some knowledge of basic logic. I'm reading this Pre-Algebra book on OpenStax for your reference if it matters.
In the textbook it defines the "Subtraction Property of Equality" as follows:
Subtraction Property of Equality
For any numbers $a, b, \text{ and } c$
If $a=b$, then $a-c=b-c$
Similar definitions are provided for the addition, multiplication, and division properties of equality.
When solving an equation we use these properties to find the solution(s) for a variable. The solution path generally looks like the following example:
Solve for $x$ in the equation $x+2=7$
$x+2-2=7-2$ by the subtraction property of equality
Therefore, the solution is $x=5$
My question is why are we able to use the Subtraction Property of Equality if we are never explicitly told that the equation $x+2=7$ is a true statement? In other words, to me it seems that we have not satisfied the antecedent of the definition to use the consequent. Should we just assume that the statement is true?
I have a few thoughts so far, 1) this 'dilemma' I've described pertains to all the arithmetic operation's properties of equality. 2) perhaps this is only a consequence of the definitions that have been chosen by authors. 3) we can always create a backwards argument that would be valid and still show that we've found a solution, so it's an 'unnecessary step' that is not discussed.

"$x+2=7$" is not a true statement. It is only true for the solution (here $5$). The point is that the solution set does not change if you add or subtract any number or if you multiply or divide the equation by a non-zero number. Such a transformation is called equivalent transformation and allows to solve linear equations with one variable.

@peter - Oh, interesting, I see. This seems trivial, but the given definition only implies that the statement will remain true if already true. How about in the event that the statement is not true? Meaning, the definition doesn't guarantee that if $a \neq b$ then $a-c \neq b-c$.

This also holds , consider for example the equation $x+1=x+2$ which holds for no $x$. Subtracting $x$ (this is also allowed) gives $1=2$ , obviously a false equation. Also , $x+1=x+1$ , holding for every $x$ gives $1=1$ , a true equation. So, exactly the $x$ solving the new equations (and no others) also solve the original equation.

Verifying the final result is not necessary , but doing it prevents many mistakes which may occur otherwise. Usually , the original equation has a unique solution that can be directly spotted in the final equation which will have the form $x=some\ number$

Our aim is to step between various equivalent statements, i.e. statements which are equally true for the same values of $x$. We might use a term like "if and only if", or a symbol like $\iff$ to show this, such as:
$$\begin{align*}&& x + 5 & = 7 \\
\iff && x + 5 - 5 & = 7 - 5 \\
\iff && x & = 2
\end{align*}$$
So what we are saying is that for any value of $x$, the truth of each of these lines will stay the same. Then, when we reach the last line, we get a statement that is clearly only going to be true when $x = 2$, so then we know that all of these equations hold true exactly when $x = 2$. We could also say that the solution set for all of these equations is $x \in \{2\}$.
Sometimes, we might do something that isn't bidirectional - for example, we know that squaring both sides of an equation can introduce additional solutions. This can still be useful, since it tells us something about the set of solutions, but we still need to do additional work to confirm what the actual solutions are.
As a simple example, consider the following:
$$\begin{align*} && x & = 2 \\
\implies && x^2 & = 4 \\
\iff && x & = \pm 2 \end{align*}$$
So we reach a point at the end where we know that $x = 2$ and $x = -2$ are the only possible solutions of our original equation, but because we performed a non-reversible step along the way we have to go back and check which of those ones are true solutions. Notice that the solution set for the first line is $\{2\}$ which is a subset of the solution set of the later lines $\{-2, 2\}$.
